# Javascript - Close popup when clicking outside of it, but not if I first clicked on the popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I made a little popup that you can close by clicking outside of it.

However, If you first click on the popup and while still holding the mouse and then hover at the area outside of the popup and then leave the left mouse key, then the popup also closes.

How can I solve this struggle?

In firefox it works but in chrome it doesnt.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rkxwe214/)

```js
$("#popup-container").click(function(e) {
  if (e.target.id == $("#popup-container").attr("id")) {
    $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
  }
});
```

```css
.content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#popup-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.8);
    
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#popup {
    width: 256px;
    height: 128px;
    border: 1px solid black;
        
    background: white;
    
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">

<img src="https://cataas.com/cat" style"padding-top: 30px;">
</div>

<div id="popup-container">
    <div id="popup">
        <p>Mark this text (hold left mouse key) and move your mouse outside of the popup and leave the left mouse key:</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Many dupes exist](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+mousedown+do+not+close+if+outside+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with another duplicate, it makes it even easier to find the answer because not everyone uses the same search terms:
"Duplicates, when identified as such, can be helpful. They act as signposts for searchers when they used different search terms than the original." https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265843/4684797

Comment: I would never uses the same search string as you "jquery mousedown do not close if outside". This would not have come into my mind.

Answer (score 1):

One was is to use `mousedown` event to 'remember' on what element you pressed. Then on `mouseup`, check the element saved on `mousedown`.

This way you only trigger the `if` if the element was your target on `mouesdown`

```js
let downElement = null;

$("#popup-container").on('mousedown', function(e) {
  downElement = e.target;
});

$("#popup-container").on('mouseup', function(e) {
  if (downElement.id == $("#popup-container").attr("id")) {
      $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
  }
  downElement = null;
});
```

```css
.content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#popup-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.8);
    
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#popup {
    width: 256px;
    height: 128px;
    border: 1px solid black;
        
    background: white;
    
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">

<img src="https://cataas.com/cat" style"padding-top: 30px;">
</div>

<div id="popup-container">
    <div id="popup">
        <p>Mark this text (hold left mouse key) and move your mouse outside of the popup and leave the left mouse key:</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thx! I will accept in 10 min.

Comment: Easy to find dupes